Request for permission (Pop - up) dialog is not showing in Android
I have the following register initialized in onCreate method of an AppCompatActivity class:
ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher =
                registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
                    if (!isGranted) {
                        Toasty.error(context, "Can't continue without the required permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

then when a button is clicked the following code checks for the permission:
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            return;
        }

However, the Request for permission - the Pop-up dialog is not showing and I am getting a Toast notification as above as permission is found not granted.
The app is running on a physical device with Android 14. I have checked the permission flag of my device using "adb shell dumpsys package MY_PACAKGE_NAME" command and have got the flags as -
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: granted=false, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED|RESTRICTION_INSTALLER_EXEMPT]

The above indicates - the required permission request has not been denied multiple times due to which the pop-up dialog might not show anymore. The flags "USER_SET | USER_FIXED" is not found which means similar to "don't ask again" as mentioned in this google developer documentation link.
Both my app manifest and the merged manifest has the following -
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

My build.gradle file has the following -
minSdkVersion 28
targetSdkVersion 34

I have tried with clear all data, then complete uninstalling of the app and reinstalling the app with no results.
The pop-up is showing on Emulator running with Android 12L.
I have tried enabling all the permissions required from the "App Info > App permissions" - still my app fails to read external storage i.e. all the images from the external media bucket (from other shared folders - from other apps like facebook, whatsapp, download folder etc. Only DCIM camera folder pictures are being read by my app).


The pop-up is showing on Emulator running with Android 12L.

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE does not exist on Android 13 and higher.

from other shared folders - from other apps like facebook, whatsapp, download folder etc.

You do not have filesystem access to arbitrary files placed on external storage by arbitrary apps. Most apps should use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument). File managers can request the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, which the user must grant manually and requires Play Store approval.

As per your provided link, I have changed my code with "Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" instead of what was before. ADB shell command shows - "android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES: granted=false, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED]", my manifest includes that, still I do not see a pop-up. Any idea why? @commonsware

@mizelhozal: I have no idea. If you visit your app's page in the Settings app, do you see this permission show up as something that can be granted manually?

So apparently the "Photos and videos" permission in "App info" settings which was set as "Granted" manually before by me was hampering with the pop-up. Now, after I disabled it manually then re-run my app the pop-up appears. But even after allowing it when I check through ADB shell command both READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_MEDIA_IMAGES shows as - "granted=false" - such a strange behavior! - and as well only DCIM - Camera Images are shown in my app. @commonsware

The "Storage Access Framework ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument" which you mentioned in your reply - can I use that for fetching all the Uri(s) of the mime type "image/*" - that way may be I can access all the images paths. @commonsware

Update: Although ADB shell command shows "granted=false", my app register finds the required permission as "Granted" and no more shows a Toast notification when the button is clicked afterwards. I am now confused, actually what is going on? @commonsware

@mizelhozal: There are no "paths", as there is no requirement for images to be stored on the filesystem where your app has access. If you are looking for images, you might consider the Photo Picker. Either way, use the Uri values you get back properly, such as by passing them to your favorite image-loading library. With regards to that adb command, I have never used it.
